# iOS Shortcuts app default save location

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I have created a shortcut on my phone which essentially lets me save a photo to a folder of my choosing with a name of my choosing.

My shortcut is set to ask where to save each time. Until recently, it would default to the place I had last saved to, which was generally the place I wanted. A few months ago it changed to always default to a particular folder which is one I never want.

Any ideas why? I thought maybe it is defaulting to the folder I was last in when using the Files app, but it’s not.